# How to schedule a bash script to run at a certain time

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, sh

I'm using the code

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    ffmpeg -re -i "input" output.mp4
done
```

to loop a `.sh` file. Is there a way to edit this so it starts at 5pm CST every day and then stops at 9pm CST? Like a timer, so it doesn't run 24/7, but starts and stops itself like a task on Windows?

Comment: Google "cron" ..

Comment: As said, look at `cron`: you can start the job at 5pm and kill it at 9pm. I would add a bit of code to handle a SIGKILL in your script, if you need to do anything before quitting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

work() {
    # put your job here e.g.
    ffmpeg -re -i "input" output.mp4
}

echo "Launching background job..."
work &
workPID=$!
RUNNING=true

while true; do
    # If no child process, then exit
    [ $(pgrep -c -P$$) -eq 0 ] && echo "All done" && exit
    HOUR="$(date +'%H')"
    if [ $HOUR -ge 17 -a $HOUR -lt 21 ] ; then
        if [ "$RUNNING" == false ]; then
            echo "Start work..."
            kill -CONT $workPID
            RUNNING=true
        fi
    else
        if [ "$RUNNING" == true ]; then
            echo "Stop work..."
            kill -TSTP $workPID
            RUNNING=false
        fi
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

The script launches the job as a child process with `work &`, then monitors that process and freezes/unfreezes it as required.